# Conditional formatting based on date older than 18 months ago

Tags: google-sheets

Seems simple enough... I just want this cell to turn red if the date it contains is older than 18 months.  When I add this to the condition:

```
(datevalue(today()) - datevalue(a1)) > (18*30)
```

But when I do this, the cell doesn't change when I change the date to be older than this i.e. 1/1/1999

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the equal sign in front of your formula:

**=**(datevalue(today()) - datevalue(a1)) > (18*30)